# Is it possible to validate a text field with regex in WiX?

Tags: regex, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have added a custom dialog 'StandardUI.wxs' to my setup file. It has a text field Passkey.

```
   <Control Id="PasskeyLabel" Type="Text" X="18" Y="139" Width="342" Height="12" Text="Passkey *" TabSkip="no" />

    <Control Id="PasskeyEdit" Type="Edit" Password="yes"  X="18" Y="151" Width="150" Height="18" Property="USERACCPASSKEY" Text="[User]" TabSkip="no" Sunken="yes" Indirect="no" />
    <Control Id="PasskeyLabel2" Type="Text" X="18" Y="174" Width="342" Height="12"  Text="{\Red}* Passkey should be at least 8 characters long, and contain at least one non-alphanumeric character" TabSkip="no" />
```

Is it possible to validate passkey with a regex string ?

Answer (score 2):

I was ultimately able to do this using the following link!

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/control-your-controls/